# Which version of Jedis client supports AWS Redis in Cluster mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, jedis, cluster-mode

We are on older version of the Jedis client, was wondering which version started support for AWS Elasticache Redis in cluster mode

Answer (score 1):

Support for Redis Cluster was added in v2.3.0, [release notes](https://github.com/redis/jedis/releases/tag/jedis-2.3.0). But there are fixes for cluster commands all up to the latest version [v3.6.0 release notes](https://github.com/redis/jedis/releases/tag/jedis-3.6.0) so if possible best to keep up with the Jedis client.